# Copying part of an image with GIMP (Mac) places the png logo on the clipboard instead?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, clipboard, gimp

Whenever I open a .png in GIMP and try to copy the current selection to the clipboard the png file icon image is inserted in the clipboard instead. Pasting does not seem to be a problem however.

Anyone knows what causes this, and how this can be fixed?

Comment: If pasting isn't a problem then how are you determining what's being placed on the clipboard?

Comment: Good question. I tested some more, first by copy-pasting in Paintbrush, which worked, and then pasting into GIMP, which also worked. However, after trying to copy something in GIMP, I noticed the clipboard still contained the old content. So copying doesn't seem to work for me at all in GIMP. As for the png icon image, I did copy some .png files around in Finder, and apparently image editing programs handle such content by displaying the file type icon image (both Paintbrush and GIMP do this).

Comment: Apparently this is a problem with X11 on Mac, with the X11 clipboard not being shared with other applications.